# Popup Keyboard like Android Default keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events

Imagine a normal keyboard in android (like English). When pressing and holding A for a while, a new menu with á, ä and other buttons popups up. And while still holding the first finger down on screen, you slide it on top of another of those buttons. As you slide it over a button, it gets into highlighted mode , and when you slide out the highlighting is turned off. If you release the finger, the popup buttons disappear. If you held the finger over one of the buttons, that button's character is being typed into the text field

How can i achieve this functionality on andriod. Any help will be deeply apreciated.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/marshmallow-release

Comment: I have created whole custom keyboard. so can you please explain about how to integrate that functionality in my keyboard using this link. @R.Zagórski

Comment: See [this class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/marshmallow-release/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/MoreKeysPanel.java) of Android keyboard project. Find out what it is responsible for and look for it's usages in the project.

Comment: Actually i am a beginner in andriod. so please don't mind me asking so many questions. Can you tell me how to build this keyboard project in andriod studio ?

Comment: btw !! a reference to a source code that can be imported in andriod studio will be deeply appreciated!!