# popup window in custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-view, android-input-method, android-popupwindow

I work in a custom keyboard. I know about ppupkeyboard (and popup character) to create a popup characters in long press on a key.
first watch this video

https://www.mediafire.com/file/nbuotyewdcrmbht/20171007_161400.mp4

I want a popupwindow(or any widget) that can came up like popup character such that it came up in longpress an "with out finger up" by moving finger on items and send character in up event.
part of this question is some other wheres (but not answered) like
[Android softkeyboard popup view on key long press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218574/android-softkeyboard-popup-view-on-key-long-press)
and
[Popup Keyboard like Android Default keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178539/popup-keyboard-like-android-default-keyboard)
and 
[Android custom keyboard popup keyboard on long press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390175/android-custom-keyboard-popup-keyboard-on-long-press)
and here
[how to make popup characters swipe not clicked in custom android keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049288/how-to-make-popup-characters-swipe-not-clicked-in-custom-android-keyboard)